# Install Arrow navigation in Blogger

Tags: url, navigation, blogger

HI , I found this script that allows me to navigate on my blogger blog with arrows , but I don't know how to configure it  for older and newer posts. Can you help me ?
I dont know how to set the proper parameter.

This is the script !

[Tumblr Style Keyboard Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404312/tumblr-style-keyboard-navigation)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

    function KeyCheck(e)
        {
           var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

           switch(KeyID)
           {

              case 37:
              window.location = "{PreviousPage}";
              break;


              case 39:
              window.location = "{NextPage}";
              break;
           }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to activate Arrow Key Navigation

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onkeyup = function(event)
{
if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA' || document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT') return;
event = event || window.event;
switch(event.keyCode)
{
case 37:
var newerLink = document.getElementById('Blog1_blog-pager-newer-link');
if(newerLink !=null) window.location.href = newerLink.href;
break;
case 39:
var olderLink = document.getElementById('Blog1_blog-pager-older-link');
if(olderLink!=null) window.location.href = olderLink.href;
}
};
</script>
```

and if you are not sure where to add this, then the Widget installer on my blog will help you out - http://www.bloggerplugins.org/2013/05/arrow-key-navigation-widget-for-blogger.html